# Ruby on rails, @current_user is set null when reloding webseite or changing page

Tags: ruby, session, ruby-on-rails-5, session-cookies

I have created a Ruby on rails application where you can create a account. When you then log your self in, a session is created. In the ApplicationController.rb there is a before_action where it is checked if a user is logged in, except for the views register and welcome. And I have a @current_user variable which is true when there is a user logged in.
The login works fine. When you press the login button a session is created but as soon as I reload the page or click on a link to an other page, the @current_user equals null.
The session still exists, but the @current_user is false.

How can I get a session to last until the user clicks on a logout button? Or how can i fix my @current_user variable?

Thanks for your help!

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :require_login, except: [:welcome, :register, :create]

  private

  def require_login
    unless @current_user
      #reset_session
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in"
      render json: {status: "You are not logged in", user: @current_user, session: session}
      #render sessionhandling_welcome_path
    end
  end
end
```

**current_user_concern.rb**

```
module CurrentUserConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :set_current_user
  end

  def set_current_user
    if session[:user_id]
      @current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])
    end
  end
end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentUserConcern

  def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params["user"]["email"]).try(:authenticate, params["user"]["password"])
    if user
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      session[:expires_at] = Time.current + 1.minutes
      #render "sessionhandling/home"
      render json: {status: :created, logged_in: true, user: user, expires_at: session}
    else
      render json: {status: 401}
    end
  end

  def logged_in
    if @current_user
      render json: {logged_in: true, user: @current_user}
    else
      render json: {logged_in: false}
    end
  end

  def logout
    reset_session
    render json: {status: 200, logged_out: true}
  end
end
```

**home.html.erb**

```
<h1>Home</h1>
<%= link_to "Controllpanel", sessionhandling_controllpanel_path %>
<%= link_to "Logout", logout_path %>
```

Comment: I believe you need to include `CurrentUserConcern` into `ApplicationController`.

Comment: Why sperate `set_current_user` and `require_login` these two functions into two locations, according my understanding, you should always call `set_current_user` before `require_login`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing this part:

**application_controller.rb**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include CurrentUserConcern # This is missing

  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
  before_action :require_login, except: [:welcome, :register, :create]

  private

  def require_login
    unless @current_user
      #reset_session
      flash[:error] = "You must be logged in"
      render json: {status: "You are not logged in", user: @current_user, session: session}
      #render sessionhandling_welcome_path
    end
  end
end
```

Also, I would change the `CurrentUserConcern` to handle the `#require_login` as well. There is no guarantee of which `before_action` will run first, `require_login` or `set_current_user` and even if it is guaranteed then it's confusing.